# How to place expander chevron on the left?

Tags: xaml, expander, winui-3

By default the expander chevron is placed on the right:

[image: Expander header with chevron on the right]

```
<Expander
     Header="This text is in the header"
     Content="This is in the content"/>
```

How can I make the chevron be on the left of the header text?

Looking at the [Expander class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.expander?view=winui-3.0) I wasn't able to find promising ExpanderChevron styles.

Looking at the Live Visual Tree I can see the chevron is in the second column of a grid. I looked at trying to override the column via a style, but couldn't figure it out.

[image: Live visual tree of xaml structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

The first option is to create a custom template. You could copy the default template for the `ToggleButton` from [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/Expander/Expander.xaml) and edit as per your requirements.

The second option is to create your own custom `Expander` control that extends the existing one and programmatically move the elements:

```
public class CustomExpander : Expander
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        ToggleButton tb = GetTemplateChild("ExpanderHeader") as ToggleButton;
        if (tb != null)
            tb.Loaded += TbLoaded;
    }

    private void TbLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)sender;
        tb.Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 16, 0);
        tb.Loaded -= TbLoaded;
        ContentPresenter cp = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(tb);
        Border border = FindVisualChild<Border>(tb);
        if (cp != null && border != null)
        {
            Grid.SetColumn(cp, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
            border.Margin = new Thickness(8, 0, 20, 0);
        }
    }

    private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject visual) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
            if (child != null)
            {
                T correctlyTyped = child as T;
                if (correctlyTyped != null)
                    return correctlyTyped;

                T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (descendent != null)
                    return descendent;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to update your XAML markup to use your custom control:

```
<local:CustomExpander Header="This text is in the header" Content="This is in the content" />
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find the `HeaderTemplate` definition from [Expander.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/Expander/Expander.xaml), so I ended up going for option 2. The CustomExpander works great, thank you!